# If the prime number $p$ divides the number $J_p = 11\ldots11$ composed of $p$ ones, then $p=3$

Tags: number-theory

$$ J_{p} = \sum^{p-1}_{k=0}10^{k}$$
$$ J_{p} = 10J_{p-1} + 1$$
$$ p\mid J_{p} \leftrightarrow J_{p} \equiv_{p} 0  $$
$$  10J_{p-1} \equiv_{p} -1  $$
Then what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Fermat's little theorem. $J_p=\frac 19(10^p-1)$  If $p$ is coprime to $10$, which is all primes except $2,5$, $10^{p-1}\equiv_p 1$, so $10^p \equiv_p 10$.  For any prime except $3$, $10^p \not \equiv_p 1$

Answer (score 4):

A quick calculation shows that $$J_p=\frac 19\times \left(10^p-1\right)$$  If $p>3$ then $$J_p\equiv 0 \pmod p\implies 10^p\equiv 1\pmod p$$

If, further, $p>5$ then $10$ is a non-zero residue $\pmod p$ so this shows that the order of $10 \pmod p$ is a divisor of $p$.  As it is also a divisor of $p-1$ we see that it must be $1$ (an impossibility for $p>5$). Thus we have our contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: notice that
$$9J_p + 1 = \underbrace{10\dots0}_{p\text{ zeros}} = 10^p$$